# How to assign a match in FOR loop to a variable - Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to assign the value of **%%~nxK** to variable **t** but it just seems impossible to do

```
FOR /D %%K in ("%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") DO (
    set "t=%%~nxK"
    @echo t
)
pause
```

*(note : There is only one folder present in \Profiles*)*

I have also tried

```
set t="%%~nxK"
```

and

```
set t=%%~nxK
```

when trying to **@echo t** from within the loop or outside the loop I only see the letter **"T"** and no assigned values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%K in ("%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") DO (
    set "t=%%~nxK"
    @echo !t!
)
pause
```

in this case you need delayed epxansion

Comment: why isit that we need this? I was thinking to learn Batch but it seems like a cumbersome language from the start...

Why doesnt echo %t% work alone without delayed expansion? Thanks

Comment: @realityStruck  here http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html , and here http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php you can get good explanation. `%X%` is substituted right after script parsing.`!X!` is substituted during command execution.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for print a variable in DOS is `echo %t%`

Comment: thanks, however changing my code to echo %t% still doesnt print anything